# How to show analysis result in jenkins and mark the build status

Tags: python-3.x, jenkins, junit

I am executing a python script which actually analyze the system related metrics based on  the threshold defined in the threshold_config.ini file.

The program can analyze data for metrics like disk, memory, swap and cpu.

For each metric i have two threshold value, one is for warning and another is for critical. 
The script analysis and produce the report in text file saying Critical or warning for each of the systems.

I want to display this in jenkins, like a junit  result, did  anyone have any idea how to take custom reports and shows them in the  jenkins junit format. Also I need to mark the build stable or unstable based on the warn and critical values.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

For the first bit (JUnit result format), you may want to translate results of comparison of your metrics against thresholds into a JUnit XML file, one per comparison. This requires low-level implementation, but you wouldn't be the first person doing that. If there is a better way to do that would depend on the exact format of results you've got.

For the second bit (passing/failing the build), you could use popular Jenkins JUnit plugin which will detect all your JUnit XML files and mark the build accordingly.